# How to sort data in R I want price column to be sorted and want the respective names to be displayed beside it

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

```
Names                PRICE        
Sony LED 32          25000
Samsung LED 32       25500
LG LED 32            23000
```

I want Price column to be sorted in descending order and respective names displayed along its side in the given below manner :-

```
Samsung LED 32       25500
Sony LED 32          25000
LG LED 32            23000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the order of the data using the `order` function. Then use that to display all fields in that order.

```
df
           Names PRICE
1    Sony LED 32 25000
2 Samsung LED 32 25500
3      LG LED 32 23000

df[order(df$Names, decreasing = TRUE),]
           Names PRICE
1    Sony LED 32 25000
2 Samsung LED 32 25500
3      LG LED 32 23000
```

If you want to save it sorted (not just print it) use

```
df = df[order(df$Names, decreasing = TRUE),]
```

Comment: can we use sort function for the above query

Comment: Sort would reorder the data based on PRICE,  but not tell you how to move the Names to the corresponding place.

Comment: is there any way by using sort we can attach respective names column to it?

Comment: I do not see how to do it that way.  That is why I used order.

Comment: im thinking that we paste the two columns and make text =0 somehow can we do that?

Comment: is it possible or im just a peterpan in fairy land?

Comment: The problem is that the sort order for the names is different from the sort order for the prices. You need to move the names according to the values in PRICE.  Besides,  what is the problem with what I suggested?  It is just one line of code?

Comment: its perfectly fine awesome i dont have any problem with that its just like having modes of transportation